# How does Int32 overloads operators?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, int32

I quickly go through Int32 struct definition, and I do not find any overload to operators like + - * /, but for String class, we can directly find them. How does Int32 implement such feature?

Comment: It is built into the language.  Also the basic reason why you cannot write generic code that uses those operators.

Comment: @HansPassant  I see, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are baked into the CLR, and are not part of the code outputted as Reference Source. Hence you can't find them.

For `String`, only two operators are visible: those written in C#. Those in the CLR are also not shown (like the `+` operator).